# Redirecting URLs with ? and & signs

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am having troubles with redirecting the following type of URLs

Redirect 301 /ch-de/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=2484&category_id=90&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=1 http://www.wedding-shop.com/de/

This code doesn't work in .htaccess file.

Would appreciate any hints to solve this problem... Thanks in advance, Lionna

Answer (score 0):

Redirect only works for URL paths without query string (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Also make sure you have at least

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

in the http.conf (or similar) that controls that directive.